# Why is "hash('md5', 'string')" faster than "md5('string')"?

Tags: php, hash, md5

On http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php#73792 it states a test which shows that the `md5()` function is about 3 times slower than the equivalent `hash()` function.

What can explain this difference? What does the `md5()` function do differently and / or more?

Comment: It may be because `md5()` is an alias of `hash("md5", )` and therefore slows it down. Don't quote me on that however.

Comment: Note that the data used in the link you shared is very small - if you calculate the md5 of a large file the difference should be very small.

Comment: As C. told try it on bigger data. Every alias in php take more time because parser do the search twice. First time it search for alias and then for original function. It's kinda php problem, but it allow to not specify the data type.
Same thing you have for value cast. (int) will be much faster then intval(). It's not alias, but execution time difference is quite big.

Comment: Oh, and one more thing. Don't use md5 anymore. This days MD5 is no more safe. Use higher SHA or other methods similar to this from coming PHP5.5

Comment: @imclickingmaniac Blanket statements are hurtful. Like everything else if you understand the limitations of what you're working with then you'll be fine.

Comment: @imclickingmaniac I'm using it to create a hash for lookup, not to be secure :)

Comment: `100%` true in early versions of `PHP` but slightly the same result in current versions of `PHP`

Answer (score 5):

**Yes 100% correct** ... that is if you are still using PHP early version of `PHP` such as
`PHP 5.1.2` to `PHP 5.2.2` in most resent stable version of `PHP` they are the same and `md5` run slightly faster in some versions

[Here is a simple test in most PHP version](http://3v4l.org/GDVgk)

You also need to note that bench mark method is wrong and changing position affect the result ... This is how to get better result .

```
set_time_limit(0);
echo "<pre>";

function m1($total) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i ++)
        hash('md5', 'string');
}

function m2($total) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i ++)
        md5('string');
}

function m3($total) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i ++)
        hash('sha1', 'string');
}

function m4($total) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i ++)
        sha1('string');
}

function m5($total) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i ++)
        hash('md5', $i);
}

function m6($total) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i ++)
        md5($i);
}

function m7($total) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i ++)
        hash('sha1', $i);
}

function m8($total) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $total; $i ++)
        sha1($i);
}

$result = array(
        'm1' => 0,
        'm2' => 0,
        'm3' => 0,
        'm4' => 0,
        'm5' => 0,
        'm6' => 0,
        'm7' => 0,
        'm8' => 0
);

$total = 10000;

for($i = 0; $i < 100; ++ $i) {
    foreach ( array_keys($result) as $key ) {
        $alpha = microtime(true);
        $key($total);
        $result[$key] += microtime(true) - $alpha;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
echo "Single Run\n";
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output

```
Single Run
Array
(
    [m1] => 0.58715152740479                 <--- hash/md5/string
    [m2] => 0.41520881652832                 <--- md5/string
    [m3] => 0.79592990875244                 <--- hash/sha1/string
    [m4] => 0.61766123771667                 <--- sha1/string
    [m5] => 0.67594528198242                 <--- hash/md5/$i
    [m6] => 0.51757597923279                 <--- md5/$i
    [m7] => 0.90692067146301                 <--- hash/sha1/$i
    [m8] => 0.74792814254761                 <--- sha1/$i

)
```

[Live Test](http://codepad.viper-7.com/QxqQvG)

Answer (score 2):

There are the same!!! you need to test it with large string to check it, i use this code:

```
<?php

$s="";
for ($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++)
$s.=$i;
$time=microtime(1);
   hash('md5', $s);
echo microtime(1)-$time,': hash/md5<br>';

$time=microtime(1);

 md5($s);
echo microtime(1)-$time,': md5<br>';

$time=microtime(1);
hash('sha1', $s);
echo microtime(1)-$time,': hash/sha1<br>';

$time=microtime(1);
sha1($s);
echo microtime(1)-$time,': sha1<br>';
?>
```

and this is my result:

```
0.015523910522461: hash/md5
0.01521897315979: md5
0.020196914672852: hash/sha1
0.020323038101196: sha1
```

Very similar!!!

Comment: Ah, interesting! So the difference for small strings is caused by the fact that md5() is an alias of hash("md5", ).

Comment: So.. not a real question?

Comment: @Pim it's seem to me so

Comment: @Mike B why not? it's real question

Comment: Running these kinds of benchmarks on PHP internals.. using interpreted PHP is pretty meaningless. Are you using the same version of PHP that was used 6 years ago? You should go directly to the source and explain the differences between hash and md5 https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/hash/hash.c#L126. You've disproved the theory but you haven't explained anything.